# Multiple comma-separated values in View contextual filter only producing an OR query, not an AND

Tags: 8, views

I have a View with one contextual filter, a taxonomy field. Entering a single value works as expected: the results are filtered by the taxonomy term ID.

The requirement is to allow an `AND` combination of terms: The argument `69,78` should only show nodes that have *both* tags.

"Allow multiple values" is selected:

[image]

However both `69,78` and `69+78` result in the same query that uses an `IN` clause:

```
... WHERE ((node__field_tags.field_tags_target_id IN('69', '78'))) ...
```

The view has no relationships. The query is set to use `DISTINCT`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there also the multiple option under validation section that needs to be configured? Also this issue may be relevant: [Contextual filter AND (,) operator for multiple values does not work](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1433622)

Comment: Looks like that's it. Need to work on my Google skills.